# mobile device interperting hover as click

Tags: jquery

I have a hover event on an element for some reason when I open the site in mobile device the same event is fired when I click the element.

```
<ul> 
   <li>
       <a class="trigger"> <img/> </a>
        <div> Text</div>
        <p>text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There is a hover event on class `trigger` and a click element on `<p>`. On mobile device when I click on anchor tag hover event is fired.

Comment: Touchscreen? If so I have seen this before, try double tapping to see if the click event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

That is how the `hover` event works in most of the mobile devices. You have to use double tap to trigger the `click` event.

Comment: Is there any other event that is not caught by mobile device that I can use ?

Comment: You can take a look at jQuery Mobile if you want to explore mobile touch events http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/api/events.html